# SQL statement for Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

TableA has owner and tablespace_name.
Table B has id, name and address.

I want to select * from table B where tableA.owner = "CSCI";

but it is unable to retrieve table B details.

Couldn't recall the correct syntax - please help!

Comment: Show the schema of both tables. Also the relation between both tables. You can achieve this using JOIN.

Comment: This is what I want to do:

    select * from country where all_tables.owner = 'CSCI315';

where the table is selected based on the selected user. but if I use join it will select all the data from all_tables table.

Comment: You're trying to decide which table to select from at runtime (where you have multiple tables with the same name owned by different schemas), right? You can't do that with a join, you'd need to use dynamic SQL, to end up with `select * from CSCI315.country`. But where and how are you running it, and where is the owner name coming from? There might be workarounds in SQL*Plus, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from country where UserName in(select UserName from Usertable where UserName='personA')
```

Comment: select * from country where owner in(select owner from all_tables where owner='CSCI315');

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "OWNER": invalid identifier

It has an error invalid identifier.

Comment: You must have a column common to two tables then only you can get result by using join or in this way